# Sendmail give error "reason=no suitable signature algorithm"

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, sendmail

I just upgraded our email server to the latest version of Ubuntu, from an old Redhat.

Sendmail is working except for one mac user.  They can't connect, and the error message sendmail gives in the log file is "reason=no suitable signature algorithm".

I can't find much information on the web about this problem.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.